# Virtual Machine server restarts mysteriously

Tags: windows-server-2003, virtual-machines

We have a Windows Server 2003 virtual machine running on Hyper-V. Some months ago, it started rebooting ramdonly once a month, so so. It restarts out of nothing leaving no critical/warning entry in EventViewer, so we have no clue of what caused the reboot. The other virtual machines on the host continue to run without problems.

The machine only hosts:

- A .NET Windows service which receive TCP connections and save data
- One Asp.net/Silverlight site on IIS.
- A MySQL 5.1 instance, with one active database which is shared between the site and the service.

The number of clients acessing the site is very low and the same holds for the service connections.

The machine parameters:

- Windows Server 2003 Enterprise SP2
- 4Gb RAM
- 38Gb of free space in C:

I've checked the "Windows" directory. There is no "Minidump" folder and no *.dmp file in the directory. I checked "ControlPanel/System/Advanced/Startup and Recovery" and the machine is configured to write "Complete memory dump" in a "MEMORY.DMP" file, overwriting any existent one.

As there are no critical events, the server is virtual and the other machines aren't bothered by that, I don't know what else to check.

Has any one got a clue of what may be happening / has seem anything alike? I'd really appreciate some directions.

Comment: What do the hyper v logs say?

Comment: Nothing at all.

Comment: Is a minidump file created?

Comment: Silly suggestion: has Windows Update somehow managed to configure itself to install updates automatically?

Comment: well windows update would post something to the app\sys logs so I don't think thats it.

Comment: I will check if there is a minidump

Comment: What you have described is far from a rare occurrence and has nothing to do with it being a VM. Simply: something has become corrupted. You need to either find and fix the problem, which can be difficult and very time consuming, or nuke the machine, reinstall and recover the data from your backup.

Comment: Edited the question. There is no Minidump file. I would like to do some more attempts to find the problem before dropping the machine and setting up a new one...

Comment: do you have another hyper-v server to run this vm on?

Comment: I've decided to go as @John suggested and prepare another VM. Thank you all.